# Does Quarkus support MongoDB GridFS out of the box?

Tags: mongodb, apache-camel, quarkus

I am beginning a new project with Quarkus and want to use MongoDB as our datastore.

We want to upload/dowload large files (> 100MB) via REST (multipart-form) and archive them in a MongoDB along with some metadata for later retrieval.

I read that GridFS is perfect for this and was wondering if Quarkus supports it out of the box?

All I can find is the Quarkus MongoDB Client documentation and MongoDB Panache documentation. But nothing specially saying GridFS support for large files.

https://quarkus.io/guides/mongodb-panache
https://quarkus.io/guides/mongodb

I do see however links for 'Apache Camel Quarkus' that DOES has gridFS support. And apparently it uses the `Quarkus MongoDB` client underneath.

https://camel.apache.org/camel-quarkus/2.15.x/reference/extensions/mongodb-gridfs.html

I suppose I could use Quarkus-Camel and just call the component to do the work, but before I went that route I wanted to know if there was a pure Quarkus way.

Any examples would be appreciated of either pure Quarkus/Panache or Apache Camel Quarkus integration.

I want to go MongoDB route rather than storing on FileSystem/Database records because I don't want to worry about transactional issues and rollbacks if I can't write a file to the FS or write the meta to the DB. I want to just store everything in one location using the large file support of Mongo.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, there is no panache-repository support for gridFS. But you can access the underlying gridFS pretty straight forward:

```
  @Inject
  public GridFSRepository(
      @ConfigProperty(name = "quarkus.mongodb.database") String databaseName,
      @ConfigProperty(name = "gridfs.bucket") String bucketName,
      MongoClient mongoClient) {
    MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase(databaseName);
    gridFSBucket = GridFSBuckets.create(database, bucketName);
  }
```

Comment: Would be please expand on your answer? Maybe with a more complete example? I've never used the Mongo classes directly yet. I'm still in the research phase. I am using Quarkus and I assume I would need to pull in the MongoDB Client as a start? Where would I get the GridFSBuckets classes, etc?

Comment: Ok, I think I found that I need to use the MongoDB drivers and it includes the classes. I found https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/java/sync/v4.3/fundamentals/gridfs/#std-label-gridfs-store-files which gives examples using the raw MongoDB java classes